# Problems with graphic card and boot recoverymode under kernel 5.13.0-41 and 5.13.0-44

Tags: boot, drivers, screen, data-recovery

I have Ubuntu mate 20.04.
After booting with Linux kernel 5.13.0-41 or 5.13.0-44 generic Ubuntu-mate is running but only a gray screen will appear since some days.

When I try to boot the recovery mode of both kernel it will hang after pci check.

When I check my VGA card I will get the following

```
lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2 

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] [10de:128b] (rev ff)
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

sudo lshw -c video will return no result.
My monitor will not be detected.
An nvidia driver is not installed. I worked only with the nouveau driver.

When I boot with an older Linux kernel 5.13.0-40 generic the system will boot and I have a screen.

The same request will return

```
lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2 

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208B [GeForce GT 710] [10de:128b] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GK208B [GeForce GT 710] [1462:8c93]
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Now my screen will be recognized correctly and sudo lshw -c video will return:

```
*-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208B [GeForce GT 710]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:124 memory:aa000000-aaffffff memory:a0000000-a7ffffff memory:a8000000-a9ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Now, how can I run Ubuntu with kernel 5.13.0-44-generic and get my graphic card working with the nouveau driver?
and
How is it possibel to repair the recovery mode of this kernel?

Comment: Why not installing the nvidia driver? I've never had problems with it, Might use a bit more energy, but output is better.

Comment: I had exactly the same problems with the nvidia driver

Comment: Now, I would like to understand Ubuntu a little bit more and I work many month with this configuration of Ubuntu-Mate without such a problem but the symptoms appeared over night with the same kernel version. And so I have thought that a solution would be an easy thing.

I would like to know why a system can boot but the rescue mode will not.
I would like to know why with one kernel the grafhic card will work with the driver and another kernel will not and shows   eventual  modules.

And so I think the problem will not be a nouveau driver or the grafic card but something